# How to load anything in local storage to a different page

Tags: javascript, html, json, local-storage

I'm using `contenteditable` and I want to move everything I write or upload in it to another page by using local storage.

so lets say that this is the First page with `contenteditable` when click on Publish button it will save everything to local storage and load it in the second page which is view.html

**post.html**

```
<div id="editor1" contenteditable="true"  class="editable" ></div>

<button id="publishDoc">Publish</button>
```

The Second page in which I want to load what I added to the `contenteditable`

**view.html**

```
<div class="post-body" id="postbody">

</div>
```

I have this code that saves to local storage but loads it in the same page. but i want it to be loaded in another page

**JS**

```
const editables = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable]");

// save edits
editables.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("blur", () => {
    localStorage.setItem("dataStorage-" + el.id, el.innerHTML);
  })
});

// once on load
for (var key in localStorage) {
  if (key.includes("dataStorage-")) {
    const id = key.replace("dataStorage-","");
    document.querySelector("#" + id).innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(key);
  }
}
```

Hope anyone can help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Just copy and/or execute the code after `// once on load` on the other page. Of course you are bound to use the same `id` due to your logic, yet if it works on *post.html* it should also work on *view.html*. **Sidenote:** change your selector to `document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable='true']")`.

Comment: @Lain I tried it now and it works I've been doing it the wrong way. Thank you so much sir.